# Trying to Find Bounds on a Trig Function

Tags: trigonometry

I have the function $|\sin(\frac{N+1}{2}x)\sin\frac{Nx}{2}|$ and I want to use inequalities to get it to the form $c\sin\frac{Nx}{2}$ for some constant $c$. For a little perspective, I am going to integrate $|\sin(\frac{N+1}{2}x)\sin\frac{Nx}{2}|$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and I have the problem done if I can just get the top less than $c\sin\frac{Nx}{2}$, then it is pretty easy from there. I may not have phrased this problem correctly, but could anyone help with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have I cleaned up the notation correctly?  If I have, it is now clear that the bound is at $c=1$ and your integration trick is not needed.

Comment: Well I did not state the problem correctly, but the actual question has nothing to do with what I wrote, it is just one tiny line in the larger problem. However, I am not clear as to why the c would be 1?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Now I am slapping myself in the face for not seeing it. Thank you for your help!